# Wrong kernel version returned by uname Ubuntu 16.04.1 LT

Tags: apt, kernel, dpkg

`uname -a` returns:

```
  Linux decebal-mobile 4.2.0-35-generic #40-Ubuntu SMP Tue Mar 15 22:15:45 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

but `E: Package 'linux-headers-4.2.0-35-generic' has no installation candidate`
 and my machine says linux headers version is at `linux-headers-4.4.0-21-generic`.

I have seen a similar problem described in a [forum](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=78624).

How can I update that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can fix this by

```
sudo apt install linux-generic
```

That will install the correct kernel.

Comment: you're my hero <3

Comment: @Arronical I know, I wasn't allowed at that time as there is a timeout of 10 minutes or so